# Native Email App & Office 365 - very slow

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app

our team recently switched to Office 365 (and we use IOS 13.4). Some of us can use the native IOS App as usual.
Others run into problems: Emails seem to arrive only after a relativly long waiting period and oppening the email takes several minutes as well.

If they use a different app (the outlook app), it works much faster.
Has anyone any ideas? Or come across this before?

Comment: It sounds like a client config issue. O365 (now Microsoft 365) is actually quite easy to use.  It’s equally fast on my native Mail client as it is with my Outlook app on all platforms (Mac, iPhone and iPad). Check with your admin to see how they’re setting it up.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The thing is, that - as far as I know - have the same client config. But I will double check with the admin. Thanks!

Comment: They may have set things up for IMAP or POP access when they could have used Exchange.  That’s just one possibility.

Comment: I have found that in some circumstances the mail.app that comes with iOS and macOS devices don't always get along well with Exchange servers. You are best off using the (free) MS Outlook app. and Web mail on your Mac itself if you don't have Outlook for the Mac. I've been beset with these issues for years and neigher MS nor Apple ever fixes the problem, and Outlook is a good iOS app.